# How to monitor which process reduces disk performance by frequent access?

Tags: performance, unix, filesystems

On Unix one can use top to find out which process abuses CPUs or memory. I am looking for something similar to interactively monitor disk usage, not in the amount used space, but in the frequency of disk access. The reason for that is substantial system slowdown that seems to be related with degraded disk performance.

I tried to grep for changes in /proc/*/io files, but that didn't help much.

Comment: Are you seeing swapping?  How you do what you ask varies by platform.  What OS do you have?

Comment: @jimmcnamara: I'm on CentOS. There's no swapping, according to memory monitor, but multiple processes simultaneously access a bunch of files: compilers, linkers, checksums, etc. It seems to me, based on low CPU and memory utilization at the moments when computer freezes for a few seconds, that the trouble is disk-bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[iotop](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/) is generally an adequate tool for per-process I/O monitoring.

Comment: Yes - good answer - what I would suggest as well.  dtrace is a great tool.